# Arcade Physics Collision doesn't collide with wall horizontally?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have this bug/logic error that I couldn't figure out. My player does detect collision with the tiles with its top and bottom, but not its sides. The player is an instance of a class that extends Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle. I tried changing it to Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite, but the same problem occurs.

```
this.player.body.collideWorldBounds = true
this.foregroundLayer.setCollisionBetween(1, 200)
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.foregroundLayer)
```

In the update method

```
this.physics.collide(this.player, this.foregroundLayer)
```

[image]

The orange is the debugGraphics, and as you can see, the player(box), doesn't collide with the tiles horizontally. What is causing this? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, the error was how I defined the movement. I have to use

```
this.body.x += this.speed
```

instead of

```
this.x += this.speed
```